# Pontiac Solstice - Starter Issue

Tags: starter, pontiac, ignition-key, solstice

When I turn the key to start my car it cranks but wont start.

The starter still turns when I take my hand off the key.

When I turn the key again it starts up perfect.

Any ideas regarding what this issue might be?

Comment: Fuel pressure would be a good guess. As to the starter running once it's in the run position. That's normal on some GMs.